# Left panel of Account Register lacks Account Tree

Tags: bank-account, gnucash

How can I make the Account Register's left panel show an Account Tree, like the one in Quicken Check Register? Despite having plenty of space, GnuCash's Account tree is on a separate tab from the check register. Quicken's account tree is on the left panel, beside the Check Register.

Comment: It sounds like a feature request for GnuCash, I don't think it's possible the way their UI is built.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make the Account Tree appear on the Account Register tab.  Due to design choices in the UI, the Account Tree gets its own tab.